# Poner nombre de tabla en resultado de consulta SQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

tengo una duda sobre si se puede hacer esto en postgresql

Digamos que tengo una tabla llamada X
que tiene 3 campos, a, b,c

Si hago un select * from X me da los registros en forma:

### a---b---c

### ---------

Vale, pues a mi me gustaria alguna forma de hacer que saliese el nombre de la tabla como nombre del campo tambien, es decir algo asi:

### X.a----X.b-----X.c

### --------------------

Porque lo que hago es crear un excel a partir de varias tablas con muchos campos cada una, y haciendolo como lo hago, me lo pone directamente en excel con sus campos, pero claro, necesito diferenciar a que tablas pertenecen.

Y hacer en cada campo "as X_a"... es inviable con cientos de campos en cada tabla

Comment: Bienvenido user3313534 a Stack Overflow en español, te sugiero que hagas el [tour] y de paso ganes tu primer medalla, también es muy importante que leas [ask] para poder mejorar tu pregunta y que sea bien recibida por la comunidad mejorando tus chances de obtener buenas respuestas..

Comment: Puedes nombrar las columnas directamente en tu consulta: `select a 'tabla.a', b 'tabla.b' from tabla`

Comment: Como dice @PatricioMoracho, si no son todas las columnas, lo puedes hacer *a mano*, poniendo el prefijo en el alias. Si quieres algo más trabajado, puedes hacerlo por medio de una vista o de una función. [Mira las respuestas a esta pregunta](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5179648/5587982).

Comment: Son todas las columnas. A poder ser que sea algo inmediato, porque hacero a mano en todas... Es un poco lio, porque son decenas y decenas de campos